# How to mention jar file from github repo in pom.xml

Tags: maven, github, jar, pom.xml

I have one repository containing only jar files.

I want to mention that jar files into pom.xml.

pom.xml should download jar files from github.

How can we mention jar file in pom.xml which is stored in github repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven reads its dependencies from Maven repositories, not from git or from the file system.

If your git repository follows the conventions of the Maven local repository with groupId broken up into a directory tree and artifactId, version, classifier and extension in the file name, you might be able to register it as Maven repository in your pom.

Otherwise you should think about setting up a Nexus/Artifactory to manage your artifacts and upload the artifacts to that Nexus/Artifactory.